# What is the difference between uvm_component parent = null, uvm_component parent and uvm_component parent = " "?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

What is the difference between

```
uvm_component parent = null
```

,

```
uvm_component parent
```

and

```
uvm_component parent = " "
```

in the constructor

```
function new(string name = " ", uvm_component )
```

in a given class? Can you also provide some examples for the three above as well along with the explanation?

Comment: do **you** have a code example?

Answer (score 2):

This is more of general SystemVerilog question. Declaring function arguments defaults allows you to call the function without specifying that argument. This makes sense for arguments that are rarely different that the default. But in the case of classes derived from `uvm_component`, only the one top-level test component has a null parent. All the other components should provide an actual parent.

If you saw `uvm_component parent = " "` as an argument's default, that would be an syntax error. A class handle can not be assigned with a string.